# Enabling externalNativeBuild with ABI split

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've switched to `cmake` build system from `ndk-build`. But can't get APK split function to work.

Here is my app `build.gradle` file

The result of the build is only one file - `foo.bar-armeabi-v7a-release-1.5.1.apk`.
If I'm building an app for x86 emulator, the result is `foo.bar-x86-release-1.5.1.apk`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
    compileSdkVersion CompiledSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion BuildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "foo.bar"
        minSdkVersion MinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion TargetSdkVersion
        versionCode VersionCode
        versionName VersionName
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-fexceptions", "-std=c++11"
            }
        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("..\\release.keystore")
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "mips", "mips64", "x86", "x86_64"
            universalApk true
        }
    }

    project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'mips': 5, 'mips64': 6, 'x86': 8, 'x86_64': 9]
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.versionCodeOverride = project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.FilterType.ABI), 0) * 1000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
            output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-${variant.versionName}.apk"))
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
}

crashlytics {
    enableNdk false // too many reports for third-party modules
    androidNdkOut '.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':common-sources')
    compile project(':chess-board-library')
    compile project(':number-picker')

    compile files('libs/kxml2-2.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/StartADLib-1.0.1.jar')

    compile Dependencies.appCompat
    compile Dependencies.cardView
    compile Dependencies.firebaseAds
    compile Dependencies.googleAnalytics
    compile Dependencies.googlePlus
    compile Dependencies.googleGames

    compile(Dependencies.crashlytics) {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile(Dependencies.crashlyticsNdk) {
        transitive = true
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

P.S. Please vote up [my issue in Google's bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230422) if you can reproduce the error, but can't find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in build-tools. The ABI Split doesn't work even with the old ndk-build.

During the research I've found a good workaround - launch build right from the command line.

```
gradlew assembleDebug
```

or

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

Command needs to be launched from the project's root directory.

Much thanks for [this sudden comment](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221098#c24) :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is in your variants.outputs.each code.  For one thing, getFilter only takes one argument.  (See the [Output class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/api/ApkVariantOutputImpl.java) implementation.)

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127393/how-generate-multiple-apk-using-gradle-libgdx) for why you should not use com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI (use OutputFile.FilterType.ABI instead).  This issue caused a similar failure of split APKs for that poster.

Comment: getFilter takes one argument, it is true. There is only one argument in the code `output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)`. I tried to change `com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI` to `com.android.build.OutputFile.FilterType.ABI`, but this doen't helps.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I misread the code. You might try simplifying the code to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I tried to experiment, but with no luck. That code surely worked before upgrading to externalBuild, so I trust it.